# What is the differences on the result of Tridion UI 2012 API methods "getListComponentPresentations" and "getAllComponentPresentations"?

Tags: experience-manager, gui-extensions

I have a requirement in one of my Tridion UI extension work to call the API methods `getListComponentPresentations` and `getAllComponentPresentations`.

I want to know whats is the differences between the above two methods, in terms of object they return, and in terms of performance which one is better?

Answer (score 5):

`getListComponentPresentations` is the `Tridion.ContentManager.Page` method which returns the `Tridion.ContentManager.ListComponentPresentations` object, which is a collection of `Tridion.ContentManager.ComponentPresentation`.

This is the list of Page Component Presentations (Associated with a page. Those which you adding in CME page dialog)

--

`getAllComponentPresentations` is the `Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.SiteEdit.Model.Page` method, which returns a collection of `Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.SiteEdit.Model.ComponentPresentation`.

This is the list of Page Component Presentations which is collected from published Page.

For instance when CP is embedded on a page from page template, then it will be retrieved with `getAllComponentPresentations` but not in `getListComponentPresentations`.

The difference between `Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.SiteEdit.Model.ComponentPresentation` and `Tridion.ContentManager.ComponentPresentation` is that the `Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.SiteEdit.Model.ComponentPresentation` is more like the set of componentID + componentTemplateId properties, when `Tridion.ContentManager.ComponentPresentation` is an domain model object.